# load UITextFields using a loop?

Tags: objective-c, ios

I am trying to populate a number of UITextFields with data. Currently, I am doing it line-by-line.

```
    myFirstName.text = originalPerson.firstname ;
    myLastName.text = originalPerson.lastname;                
    myAddress1.text = originalPerson.address1;
```

Is there a way to do it programatically, in a loop?

Comment: Absolutely, but you need to be more specific about what you want to accomplish.  Do you have an array loaded with the data for the text fields?

Comment: Yes I have an NSMutableDictionary of data. In the above example its originalPerson.

Comment: Still need to be more specific.  Do you only have data for one person?  Or are you looping through many people?  Also, do you need to keep creating new text fields for each person?  It's hard to answer without knowing what you want to accomplish.

Comment: Sorry. I will be working with one person at a time. I have created the textfields with Interface builder. I just need to populate them.

Comment: What is the purpose of making this into a loop?  Is it because this big block of code is being called in various parts of the program?  Is it possible to just create a method that encapsulates this block of textfield assignments and just call that instead?  Please provide the motivation for this loop.

Comment: @Mc.Stever: you want a `move corresponding` as seen in another famous programming language?

Comment: @hans - fair question. Really it comes down to just eliminating a big code block that is copying from "originalPerson" to the textfields. I wasn't sure how hard or easy that would. It sounds like its more trouble than its worth. Thanks.

Comment: I would recommend that you just encapsulate this code somewhere else.  It looks like it would be possible to create a loop, but at the cost of making your code less readable.

Comment: @ott - yes, `move corresponding` might just be the ticket. Now all we need to do is merge OBJ-C and COBOL. :)

Comment: If they ever bring bindings from OS x to iOS, we'll all be happy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add your text fields to an array (or `IBOutletCollection`), and your keys to another array, and then in your loop assign the value for the key in your array to the equivalent text field in your other array, but by the time you've done and maintained and debugged all that, I don't think you'll have saved yourself much.